# Вызов метода компонента из другого метода

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не пойму как вызвать метод `generateArray` из метода  `quadroData` в компоненте. Код ниже не вызывает `generateArray`(пример в [codepen](http://codepen.io/while1pass/pen/OmbRYJ))

```js
class Quadro extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.quadroData(props.width)
    }
  }

  getColor(colors = ["red", "yellow"]) {
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }

  generateArray(width, pos) {
    console.log('here')
    return [...new Array(width)].map((item, index) => ({
      y: pos,
      x: index,
      color: this.getColor()
    }));
  }

  quadroData(width) {
    return  [...new Array(width)].map((item, index) => 
      this.generateArray(width, index)
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      {this.state.data.map((index) => <div>1</div>)}
    </div>)
  }
};
```

Comment: А что он в таком случае вызывает?  Не вижу ошибок.

Comment: Ошибка в консоли какая? Скорее всего ваша проблема связаан с тем чтo React.Component не автобиндит методы в отличие от React.createClass, а Вы привыкли что автобиндит. Но здесь с ходу вроде криминала не вижу

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму разобрался, я делал прототип на кодепене, а его бабель не разбирается в этой конструкции [...new Array(width)] , переписал

Comment: @PavelMayorov разобрался, выше ответил Утке, прототип делал на кодепен, ошибок не было, просто не выполнялся метод

Comment: @while1pass вообще-то по вашей ссылке **были** ошибки в консоли

Answer (score -1):

В конструкторе привяжите методы к этому объекту вот так:

```
this.generateArray = this.generateArray.bind(this);
```